# paypal - Error code 81002 Method is not supported

Tags: php, api, paypal

My problem is related to this specific error:

I'm doing a form to contain data that have to be passed to the server to obtain the token, but probably i haven't understood some concepts about doing this

Here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp">
    <input type="hidden" name="USER" value="Apiuser"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="PWD" value="Apipass"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="SIGNATURE" value="Apisignature"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="VERSION" value="52.0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTACTION" value="Sale"/>    
    <input name="AMT" value="19.95"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="RETURNURL" value="http://www.YourReturnURL.com"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="http://www.YourCancelURL.com"/>
    <input type="image" name="METHOD" src="https://www.paypal.com/it_IT/IT/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" value="SetExpressCheckout"/>
</form>
```

And here is my function

```
if (isset($_POST['METHOD'])) {

$API_UserName = urlencode("Apiuser");
$API_PassWord = urlencode("Apipass");
$API_Signature = urlencode("Apisignature");

$return_url = "http://www.myurl.com";
$cancel_url = "http://www.myurl.com";

$version = urlencode('52.0');
$nvpreq = "USER=$API_UserName&PWD=$API_PassWord&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature&VERSION=$version&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=19.95&RETURNURL=$return_url&CANCELURL=$cancel_url&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout";

}
```

Is seems that something is wrong, can you give me a tip please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you just print your username, password and API signature for the world to enjoy? recommend editing that

Comment: yeah...do you have some idea about that error?

Comment: did you check the paypal API error codes section? they list every error code

Comment: possible bad character in the URL you're sending to paypal. best guess. sorry I couldn't be of more help! Paypal is a bear to work with sometimes

Comment: which url? do you mean the string of keys and values?

Comment: Maybe if you submit your form, the code should works...i cant see the submit button or the submit js routine in your code.

Comment: Robert, how can i submit here? I have to use a button that is an image and that can't be a type submit

Comment: Put the full HTML code that gets generated here as opposed to the PHP that's generating it.  Need to see the actual values filled into the string.  You've probably got something breaking the string so it's not seeing the method parameter correctly.

Comment: You would also want to update the version number.  52.0 is very old.  I believe they're up to 100+ now.

Comment: Hi Andrew, do you think it's a matter of string? I can't pass these values because these are the keys for payment...but i don't think it's a matter of which code is passed on string because if i follow the documentation example (a form with a generic submit button sending request to the server, the request is "success")

Comment: I solved using a button tag instead of a input tag setting border to 0 and background to white. Seems to be the best result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you are not encoding the parameters twice? Im my case that was happening though http_build_query() and some default setting which was unstable for some reason due to being changed somewhere during runtime.

Basically your final call should contain & and not &, for me the final curl call for some reason ended up with being encoded as &.

Make sure you are not encoding twize, and if using http_build_query() update your function so it will be explicit on the encoding part:

```
from: http_build_query($requestParameters)

to: http_build_query($requestParameters,'','&')
```

The difference is that the last version will explicitly use & as delimiter while the first will use the default, so be sure.